# Display text on a Tkinter label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to know how to display text or a number to an empty label, after a button is clicked. Let's pretend, I want to display the number "0" to an empty label after a button is clicked.

My questions in simplified form are:

1. How to set a numeric value of 0 to a button.
2. Once the numeric integer value of (0) is set, how do you display the result to an empty label after the button widget is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind a callback helper method which would be triggered when the button is clicked. Here's an MCVE:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(
    root,
    text='Click Me!',
    command=lambda: label.configure(text='beautiful spam')
)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

...you'd do the same for `0` - the text doesn't matter, nor does it matter whether you're configuring an empty label, or a label which already has some text.

Comment: Thanks for your time, this is exactly what I needed. 